# Knife meets eye socket question

Tags: creative-writing, description

I'm writing a story and want to immerse the readers by describing the sound of a knife being pulled out of an eye socket. I can't think of a good word. It'd be descriptive, wet, and grating. It could be a series of words I could form a sentence around for this particular instance.

I settled on "shunk," but I think I could describe it better, seeing as the character is removing the knife from his own eye socket, much to the shock of the person whose perspective we're following. "Shunk" seems hollow for this moment.

Comment: If I'm pulling a knife out of my own eye socket, the only sound **anyone** is likely to hear is that of me screaming in pain, followed by a "thunk" as I pass out and collapse on the ground.

Comment: Think about this for a minute.  If a knife is stuck so far into your eye socket that you have to pull it out, then it is likely stuck in your brain  as well.

Comment: @Jre:  Actually, not likely.  The skull is behind a bone in the rear of the eye socket.  There is a small hole for optical nerves to go behind, but most of the eyeball has bone separating it from the brain cavity because injuries like this do happen.

Comment: @hszmv:  If the knife is stuck in far enough to rasp on bone, then is if far enough in that the point of the blade will be through the eye and out the back.  In either case, pulling it out will involve screams of pain rather than something like the (comedic sounding) "shunk."

Comment: Well, wouldn't 'shunk' be a background sound to all the pain screams?

Answer (score 2):

> immerse the readers by describing the sound of a knife being pulled
> out of an eye socket. I can't think of a good word.

### there is no Magic-Bullet

There is no magic-bullet vocabulary that can 'immerse' readers with a single word or description.

In fact the more you describe sights and sounds as witnessed through a character, the *less immersive* the writing becomes.

**No one knows what that sounds like** so you can't tap into some universal knowledge that all readers have to a relatable, familiar experience. It will not have impact, more likely to be *distracting* as readers engage healthy skepticism while interpreting the words on the page that are completely unprecedented.

"The knife made a sound like: SHUNK!"

Normal reader encountering completely new description of thing that never happens: "Is that REALLY the noise a knife in an eyeball makes...? Wouldn't it sound more like a knife slicing a boiled egg, or no sound at all, or possibly...?"

**If a reader starts to think** because they are being told something unfamiliar but oddly specific, you run the risk of kicking them out of the narrative, certainly breaking any intended 'immersion'.

### Use familiar words with the right emotional context

Standard (prose, fiction) writing advice is to **use your protagonist's POV to give the reader emotional context**. It is counter-intuitive, but often the more 'graphic' the description the less impact it has on the reader.

Rather than a factual audio-visual sensory data, try a protagonist-oriented approach where readers are given the *feelings*, and then fall back to universal descriptions that are already loaded with meaning, or associated with revulsion.

"a sickening, wet suckling sound..."

The above example uses *alliteration* to add an implied sound-booster to the description. **Writers use literary tricks because there are no 'magic-bullet' vocabulary words.**

The alliteration adds emphasis to the description, both with the 'wetness' of several words starting with the letter 's', but also because using any writing technique *at all* cues the reader this is an important bit of *stylized writing*. The description draws attention to itself, but in a way that re-enforces the information through style.

### Comicbook Onomatopoeia

Another 'problem' with making up a new word to describe a sound, is it's an over-used trope in comicbook art.

[image: comicbook illustration with an onomatopoeia sound effect]
[Onomatopoeia: Comics and Advertising](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Onomatopoeia#Comics_and_advertising).

This trope is so strongly related to comicbooks, it tends to invoke 'caped crusader' Jack Kirby-era golden-age comics specifically, and often ironically (for better or worse).

In the context of a comicbook, the made-up word is pure style. It does not need to be the familiar word (or even a real word) because it has other visual cues reinforcing the intended onomatopoeia sound-effect (working like the alliteration above).

However, the word alone – just a series of phonemes and syllables – has no inherent impact on the reader. The word is meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

While physical sensations are useful for creating an immersive story, they are usually insufficient on their own. Also, the more visceral the action, the more skill it takes to write and not cause the reader to pull back.

Plus, there is a logical contradiction in your question.  I imagine the victim would be screaming because they'd been stabbed in the eye.  How would someone hear the soft squish of the knife over the full-throated wailing and panicked keening of the stabbing victim.

Immersive-ness comes from evoking the reader's imagination in a collaborative way by tapping into the reader's sense-memory, experience, and empathy. A violent act on its own will tend to cause readers to pull back and not lean in.

A POV character's emoting and reaction are very powerful elements to create an immersive moment.  Feeling the sense of justice as the victim is stabbed, or its deep-fairness and senseless. The panicked feeling you get when you've experienced an extreme injury and, in that instant, realize you'll be blind or maimed for the remainder of your life, which may be very brief cause you've been stabbed in the head.  Coming face to face with death, is upsetting.  Evoking that experience is far more likely to create an immersive moment than "the knife schlurped as it came out."

Answer (score 0):

### "Shunk" is not the best sound for this situation.

Consider that we're talking about an eyeball. An eyeball is not a hard object. It is very soft and wet. "Shunk" is more a sound that you would normally apply to something like a sword being stuck in the ground with a strong blow. It requires a great deal of a longer blade in something very hard(taking a lot of energy) to make a sound like "shunk". You would want to do something that is shared by the two characteristics of the eyeball I mentioned. Not something like a soft "plop" or something wet like a "sploosh"; you probably want something like a "squish-swing", or something like that.

Otherwise, Wetcircuit provides a rather good answer about making your own sounds, which I would also suggest.